# Was Chingari ever actually released?

Tags: indian-cinema, an-idiot-abroad

In season 3 of *An Idiot Abroad*, Karl Pilkington and Warwick Davis end up participating in an Indian film named *Chingari*.  However, I can't seem to find any information on the movie other than the trailer and news articles pertaining to the two British actors participating in the film.  Also, there seems to be another movie with the [same name](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3058830/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_2) that came out in 2012, and that's the one that's credited under Karl Pilkington.

So, did this film actually release?  What was the film about?

Comment: @Paulie_D it's possible this is wrong, but was going off of this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_An_Idiot_Abroad_episodes#cite_note-33

Comment: @Paulie_D also, the plot description here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chingari_(2012_film)  doesn't really match up with the scenes/tone in the trailer: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=botirPAQqCc

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are many films with same name Chingaari or Jingaari. This word means a spark or flame depending on the context. The movie which is linked in the question is a Kannada movie. It is different from the movie Karl Pilkington and Warwick Davis acted. The film they acted is Chingari(2012) a [bhojpuri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhojpuri_cinema) film.  Warwick Davis acted as a journalist in this movie. This is a low budget movie.

[Here](https://youtu.be/Q3OcNlvGXlA?t=16) is the clip in the trailer where  Karl Pilkington and Warwick Davis are shown.  Warwick Davis says the dialogue :

> This is jungleraaj(Rule of Goons).

Warwick Davis and Karl Pilkington are seen complaining about the crime they witnessed at a police station and are not happy with the police's reaction to the complaint.

**Plot:**

By watching the movie trailer, it is clear that the movie is set in a state where Goons are not bound by the law. The protagonist of the movie is a female. The Villain in the movie is a goon who is also the brother of member of Legislative assembly. Due to political support, even the cops are afraid to take action on his crimes. He somehow messes with the protagonist of the movie and her husband gets killed by villain's men. She finally gets courage to revolt on this issue and kills the villain. This movie potrays the condition of crime in the society and the status of women.

[This](https://www.asklaila.com/movie/Bettiah/chingari/8091/) website says that the movie released on October 12, 2012 but the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rani_Chatterjee#Selected_filmography) page of the protagonist and [other](http://www.bhojpurifilmiduniya.com/2016/11/rani-chatterjee-all-films-list.html) websites doesn't show any details of the movie being released. The former website is the only website to say that the movie is released.